# Error when generating typed transformations from JSON data with case class

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, kryo

I am trying to to create a strongly typed dataset for the case class Person. This is my code right now:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

case class Person(name: String,phone: String,address :Map[String, String])

val schema = ArrayBuffer[StructField]()
schema.appendAll(List(StructField("name", StringType), StructField("phone", StringType)))
schema.append(StructField("address", MapType(StringType, StringType)))

implicit val personEncoder = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[Person]

val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("dynamic-json-schema").setMaster("local")
val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val jsonDF = spark.read
.schema(StructType(schema.toList))
.json("""apath\data.json""")
.toDF()

jsonDF.as[Person].select("name", "phone")
```

And this is the input json data:

```
{"name":"Michael","phone":"2342233","address":{"street":"Lincoln", "number":"344", "postcode":"3245NM"}}
{"name":"Tony","phone":"4342223","address":{"street":"Pizla", "number":"12", "postcode":"9088AL"}}
{"name":"Maria","phone":"32233454","address":{"street":"Coco", "number":"32", "postcode":"8900PO"}}
```

Although I am getting the next error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Try to map struct<address:struct<number:string,postcode:string,street:string>,name:string,phone:string> to Tuple1, but failed as the number of fields does not line up.;
```

I am using spark 2.2.0. 
I understand that somehow is related to nested json and the mapping to class Person but what is the exact reason that spark can't convert Dataset[Row] -> Dataset[Person]?

Comment: I would try nested classes and a StructType rather than a Map

Comment: Hi @cricket_007, thank you for the response. You mean to change the Map[String, String] -> StructType for the Person class?

Comment: Because to set address to StructType I have tried already and I had exactly the same error

Comment: I more meant to create an Address class to be placed inside the Person

Comment: I just tried it here is the error again 'Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Try to map struct<name:string,phone:string,address:struct<street:string,number:string,postcode:string>> to Tuple1, but failed as the number of fields does not line up.;
'

Comment: here are the current classes: `case class Address(street: String,number: String,postcode :String)
case class Person(name: String,phone: String,address :Address)`

Comment: Do you really need the schema? Shouldn't `spark.read.json("file").as[Person]` be enough?

Comment: True as far as I know it should be enough. Although I have tried to remove schema as well with the same results

Comment: Well, I'm not sure where `Tuple1` is being applied, but this section of the docs seems to support what I just put https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#creating-datasets

Comment: people.json though doesn't contain nested json though I believe there is the problem. On mapping json struct type to my class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remove the Kyro encoder, this works fine.

The nesting of your data isn't the problem, as it also works on non-nested JSON

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

case class Address(street: String, number: String, postcode: String)
case class Person(name: String, phone: String, address: Address)

object JsonReader extends App {
    val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local")
      .getOrCreate()

    import sparkSession.implicits._

    val p = JsonReader.getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("input.json").toURI.getPath
    val df = sparkSession.read.json(p).as[Person]
    df.printSchema()
    df.show()

    df.select($"address.*").show
}
```

Comment: Yes cricket indeed that was it. I tried with the Map[String, String] as well and it works fine also. Thank you for your help